# My php with mssql where clause doesnt work

Tags: php, ios, objective-c, sql-server

here is my php code:

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
$con = mssql_connect('xx.xx.xx.xx\\MSSQLSERVER2012', 'user', 'password');
@mssql_select_db('mydbname') or die ("Error");

$username = $_POST['username'];
$query = "SELECT username,password FROM users WHERE username='$username'";
$result = mssql_query($query, $con) or die ("Error");
$num = mssql_num_rows($result);

$rows = array();

while ($r = mssql_fetch_assoc($result))

{
    $rows[] = $r;

if($_POST['username'] == $username)
{
    echo '{"success":1}';
}else
{
    echo '{"success":0,"error_message":"Username and/or password is invalid."}';
}
}echo json_encode($rows);

mssql_close($con);
```

and ios code:

```
@try {

    if([[txtUsername text] isEqualToString:@""] || [[txtPassword text] isEqualToString:@""] ) {
        [self alertStatus:@"Please enter both Username and Password" :@"Login Failed!"];
    } else {
        NSString *post =[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"KullaniciAdi=%@",[txtUsername text]];
        NSLog(@"PostData: %@",post);

        NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://mysite/json/login.php"];

        NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

        NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];

        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
        [request setURL:url];
        [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
        [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
        [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
        [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
        [request setHTTPBody:postData];

        [NSURLRequest setAllowsAnyHTTPSCertificate:YES forHost:[url host]];

        NSError *error = [[NSError alloc] init];
        NSHTTPURLResponse *response = nil;
        NSData *urlData=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];

        NSLog(@"Response code: %d", [response statusCode]);
        if ([response statusCode] >=200 && [response statusCode] <300)
        {
            NSString *responseData = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            NSLog(@"Response ==> %@", responseData);                    

            SBJsonParser *jsonParser = [SBJsonParser new];
            NSDictionary *jsonData = (NSDictionary *) [jsonParser objectWithString:responseData error:nil];


            NSLog(@"%@",jsonData);



            NSInteger success = [(NSNumber *) [jsonData objectForKey:@"success"] integerValue];




            NSLog(@"%d",success);
            if(success == 1)
            {
                NSLog(@"Login SUCCESS");
                [self alertStatus:@"Logged in Successfully." :@"Login Success!"];

            } else {

                NSString *error_msg = (NSString *) [jsonData objectForKey:@"error_message"];
                [self alertStatus:error_msg :@"Login Failed!"];
            }

        } else {
            if (error) NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
            [self alertStatus:@"Connection Failed" :@"Login Failed!"];
        }
    }
}
@catch (NSException * e) {
    NSLog(@"Exception: %@", e);
    [self alertStatus:@"Login Failed." :@"Login Failed!"];
}
```

If I use mysql database works fine, but msssql doesnt. How can I fetch in my project from mssql.
My json data log:

```
 [__NSArrayM objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8c8bf50
```

if I delete json encode in php then response null.

Comment: The response `json_encode($rows);` is not a valid json. try with the valid one]

Comment: sorry, I dont understand please show me a valid one?

Comment: you'r responding as NSString,  later the result are converting to the json at PHP. while in IOS, trying to get the objectForKey:<keyName>, but not found

Comment: please more help for change. I know i want to much but i really need it

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell what's going on without seeing the jsonBody that is being sent by your mssql database, but if I had to guess, you are getting this issue because of this line.

```
NSDictionary *jsonData = (NSDictionary *) [jsonParser objectWithString:responseData error:nil];
```

Looking at the SBJson library the selector objectWithString: can return an NSDictionary or an NSArray, so if your json payload looks like this:

```
[{"record":1,"value":"record1"},{"record":2,"value":"record2"}]
```

then objectWithString will return an array so that when you call

```
NSInteger success = [(NSNumber *) [jsonData objectForKey:@"success"] integerValue];
```

you get a crash, for sending a selector intended for a NSDictionary to an NSArray. Try something like this:

```
id parsedObject = [jsonParser objectWithString:responseData error:nil];
if ([parsedObject isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
   //Treat as a NSDictionary        


} else if ([jsonData isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
    //Treat as an array of NSDictionaries

}
```